# How to display image with bounded Form

Tags: django, imagefield

my view.py

```
form_data = {
    'message':data_dict['message']
    'contract_image': data_dict['contract_image']}

form = AddMcc(form_data)
print form['message'] // <input name="message" type="text" value="apple" /> (apple equal data_dict['message'] I got)
print form['contract_image'] // <input class=".." name="contract_image" type="file" />
return render(request, 'hellow.html', {'form': form, 'contract_image': data_dict_alipay['contract_image']})
```

my template

```
<div class="am-form-group am-u-lg-8">
  <p>{{ form.subject }}</p>
  <p>{{ form.message }}</p>
</div>
<div class="am-form-group am-form-file am-u-lg-8">t
  <div class="upload_image am-u-lg-2">
  <button type="button" class="am-btn am-btn-default am-btn-sm">
  {{ form.contract_image }}
  <img class="image_thumb" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ contract_image}}" />
  <button>edit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

form.py

```
contract_image = forms.ImageField(
    required = True,
    widget=forms.FileInput(
        attrs={
            'id': 'id_contract_image'
        }
    ),
)
```

This template is for users to edit their infos.template shows infos belong to users.If users want to change the message or contract_image,they can edit them directly.Now my problem is,if the user don't want to change his contract_image,but form.contract_image still require something in it (require = true),how to set its default value if not empty?

Comment: Just to clarify: 1) Can you edit your post and upload your form so that we can have a look? 2) When you click on the input button (form.contract_image), what do you want to do? Because currently, you aren't using an HTML `<form action='foo'>`, you're just using the input box of your form. 3) What do you mean by "If I don't change the image by using input bottom"? Do you mean if you don't post the image using the input button? If yes, how what other way are you using to upload the image (if you aren't using the form's input button)?

Comment: Thanks,bro.I edited it. 2) uploat image it user want to change it  3) If I don't want to change contract_image, form.is_valid() return false,because I havn't set contract_image's value. But in fact, I had set it earlier.